# Why am I not getting unique pointers for the returned functions?

Tags: go

```
func creator(v string) func() string {
    return func() string {
        return v
    }
}

func getters(runID string) []func() string {
    return []func() string{
        creator(runID),
    }
}

func TestPtrs(t *testing.T) {
    var allVals []func() string
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        vals := getters(fmt.Sprintf("run-%d", i))
        for j := range vals {
            fmt.Printf("[%d] Valueof %v pointer: %d\n", i, reflect.ValueOf(vals[j]), reflect.ValueOf(vals[j]).Pointer())
        }
        allVals = append(allVals, vals...)
    }

    for i := range allVals {
        fmt.Printf("[%d] %s\n", i, allVals[i]()) // Works as expected
    }
}
```

In this case, even though the anonymous function returned by the creator function has similar body it's essentially different than each other because of the reliant on the closure value `v`. However, why are they still returning the same pointer value?

Comment: The documentation for [Value.Pointer](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Pointer) says *If v's Kind is Func, the returned pointer is an underlying code pointer, but not necessarily enough to identify a single function uniquely. The only guarantee is that the result is zero if and only if v is a nil func Value.*.  The functions have the same underlying code pointer.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks. In that case what would be my best option to uniquely identify these functions?

Comment: There is no option short of using the unsafe package to examine the the function value internals.  This endeavor is even more challenging if you expect two calls to `creator("foo")` to return the same identity.

Comment: Function identity should be an extensional concept, not an intensional.

Comment: Also note that in your code, you're dealing not with _functions_ (as in "pure functions", whose sole input is through their arguments; I know PL purists would catch me here, but let's not digress) but rather with _closures:_ each invocation of `creator` produces _something callable,_ which, when called, also refers to a memory location containing the value of `v` at the time of the call to `creator`. These locations are distinct in distinct calls which naturally produces distinct closures. The fact _the code_ of these "callables" is truly the same is irrelevant because they are not "only code"

Comment: It possibly can be said that it's impossble for that `v` in `creator` to be shared between code other than that of `creator` and a closure it constructs, but it's, again, irrelevant: even if a particular implementation of Go would use JIT and would compile the closure's code on the spot after inlining the value of `v` (instead of embedding a reference to it into the closure's code), you would anyway have different closures for calls with different values of `v`. IOW, semantically, these closures simply cannot be "the same".

Comment: To explain that in different words, a closure closing over a set of variables can be thought of as a variable of an anonymous `struct` type containing pointers to each of these variables as its fields, with a method attached to that type which gets called when you call the closure, and that method gets passed that variable as its receiver. As can be seen, only closing multiple times over the same _(at runtime!)_ set of variables could be thought of as producing "the same" closures.

Comment: @kostix re "in your code, you're dealing not with functions " - in Go terms, these are functions, regardless of what CS language theorists would call them. This is Go code, those are functions.

Comment: @Adrian, I would rather say they are "function values" ;-) Still, I'm truly afraid this sort of discussion have greater chances of confusing the OP rather than help them. I mean, I would love to use some neutral terminology but I fail to see which exactly. Like, I would need to tell the OP something like "these are all functions but functions _of this sort_ are not quite like functions of _that sort_ (and there are at least two other sorts as well)". That could easily make the OP quit programming altogether :-)